# Encode a piece of text to its HTML equivalent

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am using html,php to feed into my sql database. I want to know if there is any way to take data from HTML input tag, convert it to its HTML equivalent (eg © to &copy ) and then input into the sql database query.
Can it be done with SQL or will require PDO or SQLi? 
If thats not possible , please suggest some alternative

Comment: Why do you need to do so? Is your database using 7-bit US-ASCII?

Comment: The issue is when i feed data from html form , only first letter is stored in database. Is it because I am not using PDO ?

Comment: Probably not. I'm sure that people who use other database extensions do not need to store texts one letter at a time. Please let me close this question as duplicate and check the linked question. If it still doesn't answer your question please let me know and I'll reopen it.

Comment: I dont think so that both are same, thats regarding setting character set and mine is regarding converting the input. I will search for answer over there :)

Comment: Linked question explains everything about hammers and you are asking what kind of shoe is better to drive a nail. Whatever, I see you've already accepted an answer so it's alright.

Comment: :) yes that answer worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities` if you have the possibility to convert your strings in PHP before inserting:

[htmspecialchars Documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

[htmlentities Documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php)